# How can I take an argument at an index with Ramda functions?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

### Note

Firstly, I would like to post this to the code review site; but you need at least 3 lines of code for that, and this question doesn't necessitate that much code. I'm aware this question is a little vague for SO, but I can't see a preferable site on which to post it.

---

### The actual question

I have found it useful in a couple of situations, particularly when using ramda, to be able to have a function which simply returns argument `n` which was passed to the function.

The easiest way I've been able to produce that is:

```
const takeArgument = argIndex => (...args) => args[argIndex];
```

This is fine, and works for what I need, but my question is, is there a way to do this using only Ramda functions? I've not been able to find any examples of this being done, but I feel like there must be a simple way to do something like this.

Comment: something like [nthArg](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#nthArg)?

Comment: @Thomas exactly! I thought that there must be a simple function in the library for this, but wasn't able to find it, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas mentioned in his comment, this is easily achieved with `nthArg`, for instance:

```js
const { nthArg } = R;
const getSecondArg = nthArg(1)

const x = getSecondArg(1, 2)
console.dir(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```